# What´s the normal form of the generator matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a generator matrix $G=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 4 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$ for $C$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$. Its normal form according to my teacher is
$G'=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & -2 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 2 & -2 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comparing the last row of $G$ with $G'$ I don't understand why this is the case. We get the normal form from row reducing $G$, but that means that the second row should remain the same. $3$ could be changed to $-3$ and $4$ to $-2$ since we are in $\mathbb{Z}_5$ but I can't see how to get $G'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Z}_5$, we have $3 = -2$ since they differ by $5$, and similarly $4 = -1$. (For some reason, you're looking at residues modulo $6$ in the arithmetic in your last line.)

The first row has $(-2)$ times the second row added to it (equivalently, $3$ times the second row added to it).

It seems that your teacher is choosing the "balanced" residue classes modulo $5$ (i.e. placing $0$ at the center) rather than the usual remainders. You can compare the two ways of representing the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ below:
\begin{array}{*7{r}}
-2,&\quad -1,&\quad {\phantom{-}0},&\quad \phantom{+}1,&\quad 
\phantom{+}2\phantom{,} 
& & \\
& & 0, &1,& 2,&\quad \phantom{+}3,&\quad \phantom{+}4
\end{array}